# How does this function retain a value - confused

Tags: swift, function, closures

I'm learning closures... albeit slowly and I have come across the following example which provides an example of how closures 'close over' the variables/constants within their scope. I'll post the code first and ask my question after:

```
func countingClosure() -> () -> Int {
    var counter = 0
    let incrementCounter: () -> Int = {
        counter += 1
        return counter
    }
    return incrementCounter
}

let counter1 = countingClosure()
let counter2 = countingClosure()

counter1() // 1
counter2() // 1
counter1() // 2
counter1() // 3
counter2() // 2
```

I get the function block and can see how it returns the value it does. What is throwing me is how `counter1` and `counter2` retain their values, or, maybe, how the function retains the value (which I didn't think they could?). Surely every time `counter1` or `counter2` is called, `counter` resets to 0 as its declared inside the function?

I know it's right as the code compiles, I just can't understand how the Int value returned by `counterClosure` function is retained?

Comment: The `incrementCounter` function implicitly captures the `counter` var. There is an article in the Swift handbook -> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename some of your names, perhaps it becomes a bit clearer:

```
func makeANewAutoIncrementingClosure() -> () -> Int {
    // Initialize a variable, lives on stack initially but...
    var counter = 0

    let incrementingCounterClosure: () -> Int = {
        // counter is captured and its storage is
        // therefore moved from the stack to
        // somewhere that hangs around as long as this function
        // does
        counter += 1
        return counter
    }

    // Now we return this new closure, which is like
    // [ function ]--attached to its closed over vars--> {counter: 0}
    return incrementingCounterClosure
}

makeANewAutoIncrementingClosure // () -> () -> Int
// is a function that returns a closure that starts out closing over 0

let incr1 = makeANewAutoIncrementingClosure() // () -> Int
  // a function that increments its captured int and returns it

let incr2 = makeANewAutoIncrementingClosure()

incr1() // 1  this does not call makeANewAutoIncrementingClosure, it calls the incr1 function (i.e. the incrementingCounterClosure).  No assignments to 0 involved
incr2() // 1
incr1() // 2
incr1() // 3
incr2() // 2
```